# Ambiguous module name `Prelude'

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I get this when i want to recompile xmonad to change the configuration:

```
Implicit import declaration:
    Ambiguous module name `Prelude':
      it was found in multiple packages: base haskell98-2.0.0.0
```

Xmonad was installed via pacman. When i got this error i removed xmonad from pacman and then tried to cabal install xmonad. I got the above error again but i was able to solve it by removing haskell98 from the cabal file.

Now i want to reconfigure xmonad with MOD-Q the error reappears and i have no clue how to fix this. Any help appreciated.

I use GHC version 7.0.3 (from Haskell platform)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
ghc-pkg hide haskell98
```

Comment: Yeah, i just managed to get it work with following commands:

`cd ~/.xmonad
ghc xmonad.hs -hide-package haskell98
mv xmonad-x86_64-linux xmonad-x86_64-linux.good
mv xmonad xmonad-x86_64-linux`
Then i restarted my computer (restarting X would probably enough).

Now i need to automate this somehow. Also i need to learn how to format comments.

Comment: I just noticed you mentioned ghc-pkg. I tried that earlier and it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, i'm confused. I _thought_ i tried your suggestion before, but apparently i didn't. Your solution works like a charm!

Comment: "openBinaryTempFile: permission denied" *hates Win7 UAC*

Answer (score 2):

In my case hiding haskell98 unfortunately was insufficient, I had to remove the obsolete haskell98 from the build-depends list in my .cabal build file (keeping the   base >= 4   of course).
It read before:

```
build-depends:  
    base >= 4,
    haskell98
```

... and then ...

```
build-depends:  
    base >= 4
```

With that the error message "Ambiguous module name `Prelude'" above disappeared.

Comment: When I did that, I got `Could not find module `System'`

Answer (score 1):

See this GHC [bug ticket](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4958) on the same subject:

> GHC starting with version 7.2.1 will not support using the `haskell98`
>   package and the `base` package at the same time. The `haskell-src` package
>   has both of these in its `build-depends`, so it will need to be
>   modified. Most of the time, what you want to do is remove `haskell98`
>   from `build-depends`, and fix up any imports of Haskell 98 modules to
>   point to their base equivalents.

The bug ticket was closed (without a fix), and the original filer responded:

> Yes, removing haskell98 from .cabal file seems to have fixed it - it
>   did compile without errors. It looks like it didn't have any imports
>   to haskell98, because according to comment in .cabal file.